# Replace special String in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I want to remove all `<td></td>` from source String  in PHP. But don't know how to do it. I tried but it does not work.

```
preg_replace('/(?:<|&lt;)td(?:>|&gt;)(?:<|&lt;)\/td(?:>|&gt;)/', '', $sourceString);
```

Please tell me how to do it in PHP

Comment: 1. `<td></td>` 2. `<td>blahblah</td>` so what u want to recieve? 1. empty string 2. blahblah or empty string?

Answer (score 3):

[PHP example](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

```
<?php
$out =  preg_replace('/(?:<|&lt;)td(?:>|&gt;)(?:<|&lt;)\/td(?:>|&gt;)/', '', $sourceString);
?>
```

if your regex is correct in $out is your result :)

but there is one more simple way [strip tags](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php)

```
<?php
$text = '<p>Test paragraph.</p><!-- Comment --> <a href="#fragment">Other text</a>';
echo strip_tags($text);
echo "\n";

// Allow <p> and <a>
echo strip_tags($text, '<p><a>');
?>
```

Comment: @MinhLe please can you confirm my answer :) it realy helps.

Answer (score 1):

your pattern is looking for

```
<td></td>
```

but it won't find

```
<td>test</td>
```

There is a litte "|" missing. That one fits:

```
<?php
$out =  preg_replace('/(?:<|&lt;)td(?:>|&gt;)|(?:<|&lt;)\/td(?:>|&gt;)/', '', $sourceString);
?>
```

you can try it here
https://de.functions-online.com/preg_replace.html